# small parameter

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

There is differential equation $\phi''+ k^2 \sin \phi + \eta S \phi'=0, \phi(0)=\alpha_0,\phi'(0)=0$, where $\eta$ is small. $\phi=\phi_0+\eta \phi_1+...$

I use a $sin(\phi)\;$Taylor series around $\phi_0$

We have:

- $\phi_0'' + k^2 \sin(\phi_0) = 0,\; \phi_0(0)=a_0,\; \phi_0'(0)=0$
- $\phi_{{1}}''  +{k}^{2}\cos \left( \phi_{{0}}   \right) \phi_{{1}}  = -S\phi_{{0}}' , \; \phi_1(0)=\phi_1'(0)=0$

The solution should look something like this
 [image]

But I can't get it. For example, if I consider $\phi_0=a_0\cos(k t)$ then $\phi_1$ is to big(bigger than $\phi_0$)

Comment: What exactly is the problem with $ϕ_1$ being bigger than $ϕ_0$? Note that in the combination to $ϕ$, $η$ is a very small parameter.

Comment: @LutzL not so small, $\eta$ is about 0.1

Comment: For small $t$ (how small, it depends on $\eta$ and other parameters) you should get a good approximation. For large $t$ (of order $\frac{1}{\eta S}$ or $\frac{k^2}{\eta^2S^2}$, whichever is smaller) the approximation won't be good anymore. And if you want to see that the solution tends to 0, you need to consider large $t$.

Comment: @AdamLatosiński how can I get a good approximation for large $t$? I want to find an approximation function for this differential equation, for any $t$

Comment: If you establish the convergence to zero per Lyapunov arguments, then you can use the small-angle approximation which is a linear ODE. You could for instance find taking the energy function as Lyapunov function that $$ \frac12\dot ϕ+k^2(1-\cosϕ)\simeq e^{-2ηSt}k^2(1-\cosϕ_0).$$

Comment: You can notice that $$ \frac{d}{dt}(\frac12\phi'^2+k^2(1-\cos\phi)) = \phi'\phi''+ k^2\sin\phi\,\phi' = -\eta S\phi'^2$$ so if $\eta S>0$ function $E = \frac12\phi'^2+k^2(1-\cos\phi)$ is monotonically decreasing, and it's also bounded from below by 0. It has a limit then. It can be proven that assuming that it approaches a positive value leads to contradiction. Therefore it tends to 0, which will also mean that $\phi$ and $\phi'$ tend to 0. For small $\phi$ you can write the equation as $$\phi'' + \eta S\phi' + k^2\phi =  k^2(\phi-\sin\phi)$$ and treat the right-hand side as a perturbation.

Comment: @AdamLatosiński, thank you, I will try to do it tomorrow. In my problem $|\phi|<\frac{\pi}{2}\;$ is it small?